# Getting random images from unsplash api?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm new to working with API's and coding in general (started 2018) and I'm currently working with the Unsplash API. The problem is when I search for a term like "mountains", the API returns random images that have nothing to do with my search term. For example when I search "mountains" I'm getting pictures of motorbikes?! Help please! :D

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>API-Project</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="search" />
    <button id="searchButton">Search!</button>
    <p id="result"></p>

    <script src="/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the js:

```
    document.getElementById("searchButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
      let accessKey = "my_access_key";
      let searchTerm = document.getElementById("search").innerHTML;

      //let nextPage = 1;

      let url =
        "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=" +
        accessKey +
        "&query=" +
        searchTerm +
        "&page=" +
        nextPage +
        "&per_page=20";

      // Request

      fetch(url)
        .then(function(data) {
          return data.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is `search` an input element? If so, you should be using its `value` property. Not `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Turnip Thanks for the answer. I changed it but the problem's still there.

Comment: Please create a [MRE] including the relevant HTML.

Comment: @Turnip Oh yeah sorry. I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Turnip said, if the element with id: 'search' is a form input element like;

```
<input type='text'/>
<textarea></textarea>
```

you should replace your line 3 this instead:

```
let searchTerm = document.getElementById("search").value;
```

just checked the API you using, seems the way you calling it is different from the way it's documented:

```
https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY?page=1&query=mountains
```